# merge_lists function used in merge_sort of two linked lists

Tags: c++, linked-list, mergesort

I am using merge_lists function to merge two lists (for ultimately merge sort). It gets compiled but when I run it, it freezes. Please help whats wrong?

```
node* merge_lists(node* list1,node* list2){
    node* t;
    node* temp1;

    if(list1==NULL){
        return list2;
    }
    else if(list2==NULL){
        return list1;
    }

    if(((list1->head)->word)<=((list2->head)->word)){
        t->head=list1->head;
        temp1->head=list1->head->next;
        t->next=merge_lists(temp1,list2);
    }
    else{
        t->head=list2->head;
        temp1->head=list2->head->next;
        t->next=merge_lists(list1,temp1);
    }

    return t;
}
```

Please note that my class node is defined as follows:

```
class node{
    public:
    string word;
    node *next;
    node *head;
};
```

Comment: Minor quibble:  your code would be easier to read with fewer parens:   if(list1->head->word <= list2->head->word)

Answer (score 2):

Your freeze/crash is likely because you are dereferencing the `t` pointer without first initializing it.  This causes undefined behavior.  (A good compiler will emit a warning when you use an uninitialized variable.)

You need to assign a valid pointer to `t` before attempting to dereference it.

The same issue is present with the `temp1` pointer.

Comment: even after doing node* t=new node , it freezes

Answer (score 0):

You are using pointers t and temp1 without assigning values to them.  Freezing is only one of many possibilities.

Comment: but cdhowie said it first.   The "new answer" notification popped up just as I hit the "add the answer button"

Answer (score 0):

Here are some comments:

- You use `t` and `temp1` before it has been allocated. You should do `node* t = new node();` at the beginning.
- Why does your node have both `head` and `word`?  I would eliminate `head` and just have each node with a `word` and a `next`.  The head of your list would be either `t`, `list1`, or `list2.

Here is a working example:

Node:

```
class node{
public:
  string* word;
  node *next;
};
```

Merge:

```
node* merge_lists(node* list1,node* list2) {
  if(list1==NULL) {
    return list2;
  } else if (list2==NULL) {
    return list1;
  }

  // Create a new list to hold the merged result.
  node* t;
  if (*(list1->word)<=*(list2->word)) {
    t = list1;
    list1 = list1->next;
  } else {
    // Use list2
    t = list2;
    list2 = list2->next;
  }

  // Merge the remainder of the lists.
  t->next = merge_lists(list1, list2);
}
```

Utilities:

```
node* make_list(string strings[], int len, int pos=0) {
  node *list = NULL;
  if (pos < len) {
    list = new node();
    list->word = &(strings[pos]);
    list->next = make_list(strings, len, pos+1);
  }
  return list;
}

void display_list(node* list) {
  while (list != NULL) {
      cout << *(list->word) << "->";
    list = list->next;
  }
  cout << "." << endl;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  string s1[] = {"b", "d"};
  string s2[] = {"a", "c", "e"};
  node* l1 = make_list(s1, 2);
  node* l2 = make_list(s2, 3);
  cout << "List 1: ";
  display_list(l1);
  cout << "List 2: ";
  display_list(l2);
  node* sorted = merge_lists(l1, l2);
  cout << "Merged: ";
  display_list(sorted);
}
```

Comment: even after doing node* t=new node ,  it freezes

Comment: How are your lists created?  Take a look at this example to see how to merge.